# How to return a blank rune

Tags: go, rune

I'm looking at the `string.Map` function which must take a mapping function which returns a rune. I would like to eliminate runes that resolves false with a call to: `unicode.IsPrint()`

`func Map(mapping func(rune) rune, s string) string`

My function looks something like this:

```
func main() { 
func CleanUp(s string) string {

    clean := func(r rune) rune {
        if unicode.IsPrint(r) || r == rune('\n') {
            return r
        }
        return rune('')
    }

strings.Map(clean, s)
}
```

It should clean something like this `"helloworld ' \x10"` to     `"helloworld ' "`

But `rune('')` is invalid. How can I return a blank or empty rune?

Comment: Try declaring a rune, not giving it a value and returning it https://golang.org/doc/go1#rune

Comment: Tried this already: `missing argument to conversion to rune: rune()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to eliminate runes, a "blank rune" is not the way to go. That would not eliminate anything.

Assuming you're talking about [`strings.Map`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Map), the docs say

> If mapping returns a negative value, the character is dropped from the string with no replacement.

Have your mapper return a negative value to indicate that a rune should be discarded.

Answer (score 5):

From what I understand, a rune is actually an integer value mapped to a unicode character, so this piece of code actually returns the `\0` character if the condition check fails:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "unicode"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(CleanUp("helloworld ' \x10"))
}

func CleanUp(s string) string {

    clean := func(r rune) rune {
        if unicode.IsPrint(r) || r == rune('\n') {
            return r
        }
        return rune(0)
    }

    return strings.Map(clean, s)
}
```

Outputs

`helloworld '`

Comment: I see this in my test: expected: "hello ' "
            actual  : "hello ' \x00"

Comment: Try it here: https://play.golang.org/p/UNH02IuXQJL Works for me with your `yo` example

Comment: I used the playground but my test shows a different result including \x00, rune(-1) works

Comment: rune(0) part is what I was looking for to create a blank rune

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using the negative return value:

```
package main

import (
   "strings"
   "unicode"
)

func clean(r rune) rune {
   if r == '\n' || unicode.IsPrint(r) {
      return r
   }
   return -1
}

func main() { 
   s := strings.Map(clean, "helloworld ' \x10")
   println(s == "helloworld ' ")
}
```